# If a click on an iframe can be captured in Chrome's console using monitorEvents(), why can't I track it in Google Tag Manger?

Tags: javascript, iframe, mouseevent, google-tag-manager, web-inspector

The title pretty much captures it, but here's what I'm trying to do: my employer would like to know how many clicks are happening on iframe-embedded Google maps on their site. I know iframes pose challenges in this regard, but since I'm able to capture the mouse event in the console using monitorEvents(), I'm not sure why I can't capture it by other means as well. School me, please.

Comment: Learn about the Same-Origin Policy.   You can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because an iFrame really is nothing more than a page loaded in a page.
For example if you would load stackoverflow in your html page you have no control over the DOM-elements or the events happening on SO in your iFrame, that's because on the SO frame your own GTM container is not loaded.

If both pages have the same GTM container loaded (same ID) it's possible , but if you're using 3rd party pages this is not the case.